# How to restart a process in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, telegram

I wrote a bot that scrapes a site and sends me a Telegram notification if it finds what I need, it has to run in parallel with another function that reads the commands I send trough Telegram. I used multiprocessing and it works fine but sometimes an error occurs and the bot or the Telegram function stops. I need to keep them constantly on but they stop anyways, here's the code I wrote:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import telegram
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue


def telegram_send(message: str):
        bot = telegram.Bot(token=key)
        asyncio.run(bot.send_message(chat_id=CHAT_ID, text=message))


def telegram_read(messages):
    client = TelegramClient('anon', API_ID, API_HASH)

    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=BOT_NAME))
    async def my_event_handler(event):
        message = event.raw_text
        messages.put(message)

    client.start()
    client.run_until_disconnected()


def scraper(msg_list):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    while True:
        
        # Scrapes the site

        if check():                  # if it finds what I need it sends a notification
            telegram_send('Found')

        time.sleep(10)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    msg_list = Queue()

    main_bot = Process(target=scraper, args=(msg_list, ))
    main_bot.start()

    telegram_bot = Process(target=telegram_read, args=(msg_list, ))
    telegram_bot.start()

    while True:
        if not main_bot.is_alive():
            main_bot.kill()
            del main_bot
            main_bot = Process(target=serlog_bot, args=(msg_list,))
            main_bot.start()

        if not telegram_bot.is_alive():
            telegram_bot.kill()
            del telegram_bot
            telegram_bot = Process(target=telegram_read, args=(msg_list, ))
            telegram_bot.start()    

        time.sleep(60)
```

The loop in main works only sometimes, at times the function just stops and doesn't restart. It's strange because if it hasn't restarted, when I open my laptop, then it restarts. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: using `multiprocessing` with `asyncio` ?

Comment: Is it a bad thing?

Comment: well, they do different things.   [1] `multiprocessing` is for process intensive operations (large calculations), whereas [2] `asyncio` is for input/output operations (reading and writing to files).

Comment: so, if the code is waiting for Telegram events, then the code should probably use `asyncio`.

Comment: It's not actually waiting, it's listening while the other process checks. I use it to send codes of things to ignore while checking

Comment: " sometimes an error occurs" - so what's the error? Fix that and maybe you fix your problem.

Comment: The errors are all on the site's or telegram's end, I cannot solve them, and using exceptions the problem persists